# inconsistency on Grafana dashboards

Tags: prometheus, grafana

For our Java application i've created a few Grafana dashboards that get the data from Prometheus and Micrometer. We are running in a few problems at the moment. For example, we have a dashboards that shows the amount of records that are running through the application. The metric that we created is just a simple counter that increments on each record.

When we do a load test with more or less just 100 records, Grafana shows it with the exact numbers. This goes well until around the 1500 records. Beyond that it is very incosistent. A loadtest with 9000 records, only displays 5000 in Grafana and I just can't find why.

This is the query that I'm using:

```
sum by(pod) (increase(application_input_total{service=~"$service", namespace=~"$namespace", nodeName=~"$nodeName"}[1m])) * (60 - 5) / 60
```

[image: Here you can see how it is displayed with the correct numbers]

Comment: It's hard to tell anything definitive based on what you provided in the question, but coudn't it be that your application "thins out" number of processed item over time?

Comment: Additionally, what shows the query "sum by(pod)(application_input_total{...} - application_input_total{...} offset 1m)"?

Comment: @markalex Shouldn't be the case. Could be for other metrics, but the total should always be the same I would assume. The query shows the total amount of records per time period. The things between the curly brackets are just for Grafana to create dropdown menu's to select from